# Encode and decode an Adobe Dreamweaver password in *.ste file

Tags: dreamweaver

How is a password encoded or decoded in order to [retrieve a password from an Adobe Dreamweaver *.ste file](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/import-export-dreamweaver-site-settings.html), or to dynamically create a *.ste file designed to be imported into Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Javascript function can be used to encode the password:

```
function encodePassword(input)
{
    var top = 0;
    var output = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        var currentChar = input.charCodeAt(i);
        if(currentChar < 0 || currentChar > 0xFFFF){return(false);}
        if(top != 0){
            if(0xDC00 <= currentChar && currentChar <= 0xDFFF){
                output += dec2hex(0x10000 + ((top - 0xD800) << 10) + (currentChar - 0xDC00) + i) + '';
                top = 0;
                continue;
                // Insert alert for below failure
            }else{return(false);}
        }
        if(0xD800 <= currentChar && currentChar <= 0xDBFF){top = currentChar;}
        else{output += dec2hex(currentChar + i) + '';}
    }

    return(output);
}

function dec2hex(input){return(input+0).toString(16).toUpperCase();}
```

And this function can be used to decode the password:

```
function decodePassword(input)
{
    var output = "";

    if(input.length == 0){return("");}

    for(var i = 0; i < input.length / 2; i++){
        var currentHex = parseInt(input.substr(i * 2, 2), 16);
            if(currentHex <= 0xFFFF){
                output += String.fromCharCode(currentHex - i);
            }else if(currentHex <= 0x10FFFF){
                currentHex -= 0x10000
                output += String.fromCharCode(0xD800 | (currentHex >> 10)) + String.fromCharCode(0xDC00 | (currentHex & 0x3FF) - i);
            }else{
                //Insert alert for below failure
                return(false);
        }
    }

    return(output);
}
```

You can also do this online without any code using this tool: http://blog.affirmix.com/2009/05/05/live-ste-dreamweaver-password-encoder-and-decoder/

Answer (score 1):

To decode the Dreamweaver password you break the password into pairs of hexadecimal (0-9, A-F) digits then subtract from each hex digit based on it's position in the string, starting with 0, then convert back to ascii.

The encrypted password of 5470714865787F would be...

```
54-0 = 54 => T  
70-1 = 6F => o  
71-2 = 6F => o  
48-3 = 45 => E  
65-4 = 61 => a  
78-5 = 73 => s  
7F-6 = 79 => y
```

So 5470714865787F => 'TooEasy'

> We have a working example of this on our website which allows you to decode your password. You can also copy/paste your entire .ste file and it will output the needed FTP details to connect, save some time...
>
> http://www.mywebsitespot.com/dreamweaver-password-decode

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to wake up an old thread but thought I'd post my solution.  It's a single HTML5 page that can load and parse Dreamweaver STE files, decoding the password as part of that.  I wanted something simple, offline/local (so details aren't transmitted when decoding) that I could to just load an STE file in to and it would give me all the FTP details:

Blog Post:
http://bobmckay.com/web/dreamweaver-password-ste-file-decoder

Decoder Page:
http://bobmckay.com/dreamweaver-password-decoder/

Hope it's useful to someone!

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Waking an old thread, but in addition to the accepted JavaScript answer, I just wanted to leave two PHP functions for anyone interested:

**To encode a password:**

```
function dwste_encode( $pw ){
    $output = '';
    $split = str_split( $pw );
    foreach( $split as $key => $value ){
        $char = ord( $value );
        $char = ( $char + $key );
        $char = dechex( $char );
        $output .= strtoupper( $char );
    }
    return $output;
}
```

**To decode a password:**

```
function dwste_decode( $pw ){
    $output = '';
    $split = str_split( $pw, 2 );
    foreach( $split as $key => $value ){
        $char = hexdec( $value );
        $char = ( $char - $key );
        $char = chr( $char );
        $output .= $char;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create many DW ste files for a client today. I used the following `VBA` to do it straight from Excel. I used the code from @andrew-odri as the basis.

```vba
Function decodeDreamWeaverPass(sHash$)
    Dim sPass$, i&, lHash&, lChar&, sChars$
    lHash = Len(sHash) - 1
    For i = 0 To lHash Step 2
        sChars = Mid(sHash, i + 1, 2)
        lChar = CLng("&H" & sChars)
        lChar = lChar - (i / 2)
        sPass = sPass & Chr(CLng(lChar))
    Next
    decodeDreamWeaverPass = sPass
End Function


Function encodeDreamWeaverPass(sPassword$)
    Dim lTop&, i&, sOutput$
    Dim lPassword&, sChar$, lChar&
    lTop = 0

    lPassword = Len(sPassword) - 1
    For i = 0 To lPassword
        lChar = Asc(Mid(sPassword, i + 1, 1))
        sChar = Chr(lChar)

        If ((lChar < 0) Or (lChar > 65535)) Then
          encodeDreamWeaverPass = ""
        End If

        If lTop > 0 Then
            If (lChar >= 56320) And (lChar <= 57343) Then
                sOutput = sOutput & Hex(65536 + ((lTop - 55296) Xor 10) + (lChar - 56320) + i)
                lTop = 0
            Else
              encodeDreamWeaverPass = ""
            End If
        End If

        If (lChar >= 55296) And (lChar <= 56319) Then
          lTop = lChar
        Else
          sOutput = sOutput & Hex(lChar + i)
        End If
    Next

    encodeDreamWeaverPass = sOutput
End Function
```