# how to decrypt Dreamweaver site passwords?

Tags: dreamweaver

When I set a site on the Dreamweaver and configure a server ftp for the site, many times I forgot the passwords so that I want to find a way to recover it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Dreamweaver just gives you the option to export the site manager data.

Site=>Manage Sites=>select the site=>export

this will save on your computer a readable xml file with extension .ste

Just open it in word-pad or any other application to read the xml and search for the needed server password and get the value of the attribute **pw** in the tag **server**

Then use this javascript function to decrypte the password from this value

```
function decodeDreamWaverPass(hash){
    var pass = '';
    for (var i=0 ; i<hash.length ; i+=2){
        pass+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hash[i]+''+hash[i+1],16)-(i/2)); 
    }
    return pass;
}
```

Hope that it will be helpful for you...

Answer (score 1):

To decode the Dreamweaver password you break the password into pairs of hexadecimal (0-9, A-F) digits then subtract from each hex digit based on it's position in the string, starting with 0, then convert back to ascii.

Example on this stackoverflow post - [Encode and decode an Adobe Dreamweaver password in *.ste file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989010/encode-and-decode-an-adobe-dreamweaver-password-in-ste-file)

We also have a page on our website you can use to convert the passwords...
http://www.mywebsitespot.com/dreamweaver-password-decode

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to wake up an old thread but thought I'd post my solution.  It's a single HTML5 page that can load and parse Dreamweaver STE files, decoding the password as part of that.  I wanted something simple, offline/local (so details aren't transmitted when decoding) that I could to just load an STE file in to and it would give me all the FTP details:

Blog Post:
http://bobmckay.com/web/dreamweaver-password-ste-file-decoder

Decoder Page:
http://bobmckay.com/dreamweaver-password-decoder/

Hope it's useful to someone!

Bob